# Does it make sense to invert RGB image?

Tags: image-processing, rgb, grayscale

Does it make sense to invert RGB image?

I know the algorithm for grayscale images is 1 - value, but for RGB?

Thanks

Comment: Mathematically it makes sense, visually it's like an old film negative - not much good for anything.

Answer (score 0):

For rgb just subtract the red, green and blue values from 255.